# Getting 404 when trying to hit the WebAPI controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have created a project using ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework). My project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

My values controller is inherited from an MVC controller. When I hit http://localhost:20798/api/values, I do get the desired response.
[image: Values Controller]

I added ConsumerScore controller, this time a WebAPI controller inheriting from `ApiController`. But now when I hit http://localhost:20798/api/consumerscore, I am getting 404 response. [image: Error Response]

My `ConsumerScore` controller looks like:
[image: ConsumerScore controller]

How to resolve this error?

Comment: why do you have a special Route for ConsumerScoreController when you are trying to access the 'default' way?

Comment: @NicoRiff Earlier I didn't have it I added it later, thought it would resolve the error. But no luck!

Comment: That code is mixing asp.net-mvc5 and asp.net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the "ApiController" you should use just Controller in your implementation.

There is indeed to particular ApiController class anymore since MVC and WebAPI have been merged in ASP.NET Core. However, the Controller class of MVC brings in a bunch of features you probably won't need when developing just a Web API, such as a views and model binding.

for more see: [Is ApiController deprecated in .NET CORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667445/is-apicontroller-deprecated-in-net-core)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Comment: Thanks, @Paulo I think ASP.NET core projects should not give 2 choices while adding the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are confusing the idea of "MVC" and "Web API".

ASP.net MVC is used for serving web pages while the Web API is supposed to be serving data in a negotiable way (json/xml/...) to http requests.

Adding an "api/*" to an MVC route and serving data from an MVC `Controller` is not the best idea and will not turn it into a useful web service.

From the look of your methods, I suppose what you need is an ApiController but you cannot create the http request by copying the "~/api/*" to your web browser and you need to use tools like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or your browser's debugger.