# ASP.NET Core ApiController - return 404 and JSON body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Within my API, I may want to return more detailed response codes along with messages that are friendly to display to the user.

How can I accomplish this using ASP.NET Core ApiControllers?

I want to do something like this

```cs
var myError = new MyError
{
     Message = "The user was not found because they are expired",
     Code = 3
};
return NotFound(myError);
```

Comment: If your class inherits from `ControllerBase` this should work as `ControllerBase` has the method [`NotFound()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which creates a `NotFoundObjectResult` which is a `ActionResult` if you pass in an object. If your class does not inherit from it you can create it manually using `return new NotFoundObjectResult(myError)`. Assuming you are returning an `ActionResult` of course.

Comment: @Mushroomator I was inheriting from APIController because (frankly) I figured that the new .net core stuff was the better way to go, but looks like good old MVC has my back once again

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667445/is-apicontroller-deprecated-in-net-core).

Comment: @Mushroomator that's a great resource, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code return 404 and json.

```
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult test()
        {
            var myError = new MyError
            {
                Message = "The user was not found because they are expired",
                Code = 3
            };
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return new JsonResult(myError);
        }
    }
```